# Choice of implicit conversion location with a block

Tags: scala, implicit

In the following code, the implicit conversion is applied around the `println(2)` line; I had foolishly expected it to apply around the entire block `{ println(1); println(2) }`. How should I reason about where the compiler places the implicit?

```
object Executor {

  private var runnable: Runnable = _

  def setRunnable(runnable: Runnable) {
    this.runnable = runnable
  }

  def execute() { runnable.run() }

}

object Run extends App {

  implicit def blockToRunnable(p: ⇒ Any): Runnable =
    new Runnable { def run() = p }

  Executor.setRunnable {
    println(1)
    println(2)
  }

  println("Before execute")
  Executor.execute()

}
```

Comment: That's weird!  I would have expected it to apply to _neither_ statement and only wrap the `()` (unit) return value from `println(2)`.  That it made the second line call-by-name is highly nonintuitive to me also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the spec, an implicit conversion is applied when the type of an expression does not match the **expected type**. The key observation is how the expected type is threaded when typing blocks.

> if an expression `e` is of type `T`, and T does not conform to the expression’s **expected type** `pt`. In this case an implicit v is searched which is applicable to e and whose result type conforms to pt.

In Section *6.11 Blocks*, the expected type of a block's *last expression* is defined as

> The expected type of the final expression `e` is the expected type of the block.

Given this spec, it seems the compiler *has* to behave this way. The expected type of the block is `Runnable`, and the expected type of `println(2)` becomes `Runnable` as well.

A suggestion: if you want to know what implicits are applied, you can use a nightly build for 2.1 of the Scala IDE for Eclipse. It can 'highlight implicits'.

**Edited:** I admit it is surprising when there's a call-by-name implicit in scope.

Comment: I'll have to give this Scala IDE thing a go ;-)

Comment: Here's the [download](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html) site with a screenshot about highlight implicits. :)

Answer (score 4):

I rationalize this behavior like this: according to the spec, the type of a block `{s1; s2; ...; sn; e }` is the type of the last expression `e`.

So the compiler takes `e` and type checks it against `Runnable`. That fails, so it searches for an implicit conversion that will convert `e` to `Runnable`. So it would like this:

```
{ s1; s2; ... sn; convert(e) }
```

This is confirmed with `scala -Xprint:typer` on this small example:

```
class A
implicit def convert(a: A): String = a.toString
def f(s: String) { println(s) }
f{ println(1); new A }
```

prints:

```
private[this] val res0: Unit = $line3.$read.$iw.$iw.f({
  scala.this.Predef.println(1);
  $line2.$read.$iw.$iw.convert(new $line1.$read.$iw.$iw.A())
});
```

Comment: Right, and I understand the mechanics of what it does do...but it's not entirely clear to me how/why the compiler chooses to work with e, rather than the {s1; s2; ... e} block, when deciding to apply implicits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are thinking of blocks as if they were thunks, as if they were pieces of code. They aren't. `{ a; b; c }` is *not* a piece of code that can be passed around.

So, how should you reason about implicits? Actually, how should you reason about *views*, which are implicit conversions. Views are applied to the value that needs to be changed. In your example, the value of

```
{
    println(1)
    println(2)
}
```

is being passed to `setRunnable`. The value of a block is the value of its last expression, so it is passing the result of `println(2)` to `setRunnable`. Since that is `Unit` and `setRunnable` requires a `Runnable`, then an implicit is searched for and found, so `println(2)` is passed to the grossly misnamed `blockToRunnable`.

Bottom line is, and this is an advice I have given many times already on Stack Overflow (lots of people try to do the same thing) is to get the following in your head:

```
THERE ARE NO BLOCKS IN SCALA.
```

There are functions, but not blocks.

Technically, that statement is incorrect -- there are blocks in Scala, but they are not what you think they are, so just completely remove them from your mind. You can learn what blocks in Scala are latter, from a clean slate. Otherwise, you're bound to try to get them to work in ways they don't, or infer that things work in a certain way when they work in a different way.

Comment: I think you think I think something I don't think. ;-) Scala gives you syntactic flexibility so that you can treat blocks of code as if they indeed are pieces of code that you can pass around...that's one huge benefit of by-name parameters! You could easily write a "setRunnable(p: => Any)" method that would work fine with the syntax as in the question, for example. I'm just interested in the mechanics of where the compiler chooses to place implicits after hitting a surprising case.

Comment: @MattR Aha, I'm right! By name parameters have absolutely NOTHING to do with "blocks of code". And that, by the way, is one of the things I was thinking of when I said you might infer things work in a way they don't.

Comment: "The problem is that you are thinking of blocks as if they were thunks". Thunks are exactly the correct way to think about call-by-name evaluation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_(functional_programming)#Call_by_name).

Comment: @MattR True, but I did mention blocks have nothing to do with call-by-name, didn't I? If you had written `setRunnable(p: => Any)`, then you'd have a thunk because _the by-name parameter_ called for it. Since it is not by-name, there's no thunk. The fact that it has `{` and `}` does not make it a thunk, it just makes it a sequence of statements whose value is that of the statement. Curly brackets will _never_ make a thunk -- only by-name and functions can do that.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between a block and an argument; I'm perplexed as to why you've so firmly latched onto this idea that I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I liked a lot the explanation given in the [first scala puzzle](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-001).

In other words, what will be the output of:

```
List(1, 2).map { i => println("Hi"); i + 1 }
List(1, 2).map { println("Hi"); _ + 1 }
```